# Vista won't boot - just get black screen

Tags: windows-vista, boot

When I boot into Windows Vista (Ultimate), I just get a black screen (with the mouse visible and working). If I run in safe mode, it seems to pause for a while when loading `crcdisk.sys`.

A lot of research says it could be a problem with the hard drive, but I dual boot Ubuntu and that works fine and I can still see and use the Windows partition absolutely fine from Ubuntu.

I tried using the "startup repair" option on the Vista install disk but it didn't detect any problems. I have run `chkdsk` several times, with this:

```
chkdsk C: /f /r
```

And also drive D (the recycle bin). The first two times it detected and fixed errors on the C drive but now it doesn't detect any errors.

Is there anything else that could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since chkdsk found and "fixed" some errors the parition could be in a state which prevents it from booting in a way "start-up repair" does not recognize and thus fails to fix. You might want to try a re-format of the partition and re-install of Vista.

The fact that there was a problem on the disk in the first place might also indicate a physical probem with the disk. Most vendors have special tools on their web-site to diagnose problems with their drives beyond what windows does. If you suspect the disk, buy a new one and migrate everything on that disk (even partitions which are still fine).

There is also the possibility of a different hardware problem, e.g. motherboard, disk controller, but since Ubuntu seems to work fine this is less likely. You might still want to check your bios settings for anything unusual (which Linux might cope with but Windows does not).

Btw, can you mount the partition from Ubuntu? If yes use this to make a backup of it first :-)

Answer (score 0):

could be bad RAM. do a memory check using memtest86 .   also, dont rule out video card RAM.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when graphics card driver does not function properly. To get your computer working , log in safe mode and uninstall graphic card driver from device manager and reboot your computer. After you will able to login windows and Vista will automatically install the default driver for motherboard.